# Using extraction operator to extract data from a complex class hierarchy

Tags: c++, istream, extraction-operator

1 - Does it sound like a correct approach to use extraction operators to extract some data not from a file but from a big and complex class hierarchy ?

```
class ComplexInterface
{
  //...
};

struct EXTRACTED_DATA
{
  //...

  friend ComplexInterface& operator>>(const ComplexInterface& interface, EXTRACTED_DATA& extracted)
  {
    extracted.m_member = interface.someAccessor().getData();
  }
};
```

Would it be better to simply make it a member method (`void extractFromComplexInterface(const ComplxInterface&)`) ?

Is there a better solution ?

2 - Would it be possible to handle this extraction as a regular stream operation ? The `ComplexInterface` would become an `istream`, implementing some magic function in which it would say "I will send this data, then this and that...". Then, the EXTRACTED_DATA could use its regular extraction operator (`friend istream& operator>>(istream&, EXTRACTED_DATA&)`) which is already defined to read from a file stream.

If this is possible, how ?

Comment: Some much needed context is missing. I'd personally avoid the extraction, either as a named member or overloaded operator, and *construct* `EXTRACTED_DATA` from `ComplexInterface`.

Comment: The `EXTRACTED_DATA` is a buffer that will stay alive in memory for a long time, performing this data extraction from time to time. Sadly, affectation is not possible on the `EXTRACTED_DATA` (due to legacy classes preventing affectation). Otherwise, I would overwrite my buffer with a new instance constructed as you suggest.